# Call Function in GattCallback from UI thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth, callback

1. My Situation : 
   I'm communicating with a sensor using BLE, sending 'Session' objects, as strings, from the sensor to the android device.

When all the sessions are on the android device, I call a session on the UI thread that uploads them to a server using Volley. (call 'uploadSessions()')

When all the sessions are on the server, (After I receive a Response from the server confirming they have been received), I need to erase the sensor's memory. (onResponse calls 'sessionsSuccessfullyUploaded()')

PROBLEM : I can't access functions in the GattCallback from the UI thread (cannot call 'eraseDevice()' from 'sessionsSuccessfullyUploaded()')

2. What I've tried: I've tried looping,
   I do this in the callback :

   `public void waitForServerResponse() {`

   ```
           int WAIT_INTERVAL = 500;
           new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run () {

                   if(sessionCountUploadedToServer == IBSessionCount) {
                       eraseDevice();
                   } else waitForServerResponse();

               }
           },WAIT_INTERVAL);
       }`
   ```

I get this error :

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into Broadcast Intents and Receivers. This document can help:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Broadcast_Intents_and_Broadcast_Receivers

It would also help to put the callback in a special Bluetooth Service Class that extends `Service`

Answer (score 0):

mHandler is created from non-UI thread. If you want to do any UI operations then make sure you create it on the main thread.

If you do not intend to do UI Operations then call Looper.Prepare() as the error suggests to you  - in the thread which is constructing the handler.

Create the mHandler as below :

```
HandlerThread mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("tHandlerThread");
mHandlerThread.start();
mHandler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper());
```

Alternatively you can also consider using AsyncTask or IntentService - these might be more suited for what you are trying to do - background operations.

Comment: Thank you, `Looper.Prepare()` does the job, but I think It'd be better to user mHandler. basically, when the server responds to the session upload request (onResponse...), which happens on the main thread, I want to send a message to the bluetooth callback to tell it to continue erasing the device 's memory.  How do I do that ?

Comment: You the mHandler just as you would use normally. The only difference is in the creation on handler.

Comment: I looked up mHandler, it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for (unless I misunderstood what I read). Suppose I have a button that calls `eraseDevice()` When called. `eraseDevice()` is defined INSIDE the gatt callback, and sends a command to the Bluetooth device, like so : `...
            gatt.writeCharacteristic(IBRXCharacteristic); ...`.  How can I call this function from the main thread ? Thanks for helping

Comment: To make teh handler on main thread do mHandler = new Handler() from onCreate() or similar in the main thread.  To make the handler on background - use the snippet I posed earlier.